# Import a second spread sheet into Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel C# project

Tags: c#, excel

I'm stuck on the last hurdle to finish my program. I have a excel doc I want to import into the one I'm building in C#

```
wb.Sheets.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet staffCosts = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
staffCosts.Name = "Staff Costs";
staffCosts.QueryTables[1].Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\\tilldataoutput\\excelcreator\\excelcreator\\bin\\Debug\\Staff.xlsx");
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: what issues are you getting?

Comment: I get Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Comment: have you looked at this part `staffCosts.QueryTables[1]` ?

Comment: I will take a look now cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.querytables(v=office.15).aspx) link, which states...

> Returns the QueryTables collection that represents all the query
>   tables on the specified worksheet. Read-only.

Since you're getting a `QueryTable` by using an Index, you should check the collection first to check if any exist, or 2 in your case since you're looking at the second `QueryTable`.